# Anomaly in printf() function

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I am seeing anomalous behavior in print function while dealing with int and float numbers.

```
float y = 9/5;
printf("%f", y);

printf("%f", 9/5);
```

First print statement outputs 1.000000 which is acceptable while other outputs 0.000000.
Why outputs are different in both cases?

Comment: Since both operands of `9/5` are integers, the result of the division is also an integer (1).  The `%f` conversion specifier expects a `float` or `double` operand.

Comment: The duplicate is the first google search result for `printf("%f", 9/5);`

Answer (score 8):

`9/5` is an integer and it's value is 1.

`printf("%f", 9/5);` is undefined behaviour because `%f` expects a `double` but you provide an `int`.

Try `printf("%f", 9.0/5);` and the output will be what you expect.

More generally spoken: if the format specifiers of `printf` don't match the arguments, the behaviour is undefined; in most cases you get unexpected output.

Comment: lol, the question was a value-exact duplicate :D